# Powershell preview keeps auto connect to Cloud shell

Tags: powershell

I have problem with powershell preview ( pwsh ) keeps connecting to azure shell cloud when I start it with Windows Terminal. The shell settings in Windows Terminal:

```
{
                "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
                "name": "Windows PowerShell Preview",
                "commandline": "pwsh",
                "hidden": false
            },
```

However, when I start `pwsh` in cmd, it doesn't connect to azure cloud shell but just powershell preview locally. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem, I use the same uuid with azure cloud shell, not sure where are other places it's stored. I just generate new uuid for powershell preview and just launch with pwsh and it just works.